# Looping Django queryset with multiple values in a column

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm stepping through the pdb

In models.py

```
class MyDataModel(models.Model):
    id_in_database = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

sqllite table

```
|id|foo|
|1|55|
|2|55,22|
```

Error:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal:
```

with `for r in my_queryset: print(r.foo)`
when

```
MyDataModel.objects.filter(id=2)
```

but not for

```
MyDataModel.objects.filter(id=1)
```

Why is this? Is there something special about setting a column with two values in foo?

Adding trace as suggested in comments:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 81, in parse_myline
    for r in my_queryset:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 879, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1239, in cursor_iter
    sentinel):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1238, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(GET_ITERATOR_CHUNK_SIZE)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 102, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 72, in <lambda>
    return lambda s: conv_func(s.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 165, in typecast_decimal
    return decimal.Decimal(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/decimal.py", line 595, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/decimal.py", line 4050, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: 'Weekday'
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: we need more information about how you query and a full traceback

Comment: I changed the question because I get this error when the column has multiple values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyDataModel.foo is a models.CharField, while you're trying to get a Decimal from it. The types don't match. Try [models.DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for foo:

```
class MyDataModel(models.Model):
    id_in_database = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    foo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

You will need to run 

`manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate`

Which might be a bit problematic if you already have data in the tables. Which makes me wonder if you have put the value '55,22' manually in that sql tables...

Comment: I imported the data using .import at sqllite. '55,22' knows this is a 2 numbers? notice the comma not the decimal.